# Entities are not persisted into Database if @transactional is attached to certain method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I am a new user of spring and hibernate.
I have a service class, which is called by a controller.
The call flow is like this:

1. controll calls myService.create method, then
2. myService.create calls myService.persistEnity method.
3. within the myService.persistEnity method, there is a dao object which persist entity to database.

The issue I found is:

1. if I attach the @transactional annotation to "myService.create" method, entities will be saved to databases.
   however,
2. if I attach the @transactional annotation to "myService.persistEnity" method entities are not saved to databases, and I don't see any error message.

My question is:

- why would this happen? (Is this because of the call flow? i.e. @transactional has to be attached to the first method of service class that is invoked by controller class in order to work?)

Thanks.

psudo Code is as below:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service("myService")
public class MyService {

@Autowired
private MyDao dao;

    // if the @Transactional is only put here as this, entities will NOT be saved to database.
    @Transactional(value = "transactionManager", readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public MyEntity persistEnity(MyEntity toBeSaved) {

        MyEntity entity = dao.persistEntity(toBeSaved);
        return entity;
    }

// if the @Transactional is only put here, entities will be saved to database.
//    @Transactional(value = "transactionManager", readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public ServiceObject create(ServiceObject serviceObject, User user) {
        MyEntity entity = convertToEntity(serviceObject);
        entity = persistEnity(dao);
        return convertTOServiceObject(entity);
    }

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because method `convertToEntity` creates an object type `MyEntity` in `create`, and if this method is transactional, the object is being created attached to the session. But if the method is not transactional, you create the new object out of session and send it to `persistEnity`, but it's not attached so dao cannot save it without new attaching to session.

Leave transactional on method where an object is created or attach it into session in `persistEnity` method.

Comment: Thanks so much for the insight!! by the way, how to "attach an entity to session"?

Comment: You need to autowire `sessionFactory` and merge an object to the Hibernate session: `MyEntity mergedEntity = (MyEntity) sessionFactory.merge(toBeSaved);`

Comment: Thanks, I don't see the "merge" method available for sessionFactory? I see error "cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method merge(Inventoryadjustment)
  location: variable sessionFactory of type SessionFactory" 
  did you mean org.hibernate.SessionFactory ? or is my hibernate jar is too old?

Comment: Hibernate I am using are: <!-- Hibernate framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: I tried to attach the "transactional" at "persistEnity", and within "persistEnity" I added: session.merge(toBeSaved), but still, the entity was not saved.  Sorry I cannot indent for you. the code is:                                 Session session;
        try {            
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }
        
//        session.
        Inventoryadjustment mergedEntity = (Inventoryadjustment) session.merge(toBeSaved);